# Is it possible to check custom ini file syntax in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a custom ini file with configurations (does not refer to php ini file) and i need to check it's syntax. Found a function `parse_ini_file` which parses the file, but it generates warning if file is bad, may be there is some function to check if before parse?

Comment: Can't you just suppress the warning? For example `$ini = @parse_ini_file('/path/to/ini');`, and if `$ini === false` then there is some syntax error.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari can, but i's not a good practice. May be there is some function to check it before parse as i dont ned to parse it, only upload to server.

Comment: @Kirix For this specific case it is just fine.

Comment: Yes, *you* can construct a validation function. A regex is suitable if the structure/syntax is equivalent to that of an ini file. It's unclear why that effort is necessary though.

Answer (score 3):

As anticipated in my comment, I would go this way:

```
function valid_ini_file($path) {
  return @parse_ini_file($path) !== false;
}
```

clear and concise.